# Uploading file from windows directory using Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework, selenium2library

Can someone tell how can I Upload file from windows directory using selenium2library and Robot Framework.I have tried using Choose File command, but I am getting errors.
I do not want to use Auto IT for this purpose. 
Any help in this context would be appreciated.

Following is the command I have tried

```
Choose File   //div[6]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]  C:\\Users\\Downloads\\File Name.xls
```

This is the snapshot of page

[image: This is the snapshot of page]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. The proper way to upload a file is to use `Choose File`, so please show the error that you're getting.

Comment: Are you sure your xpath points to the right element? I'd start by optimizing that part, as your current xpath is extremely static and inelegant. As pointed out by @BryanOakley, we need to know what error Robot gives you to help you further.

Comment: @BryanOakley  Following is the error : WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.101)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

Comment: @Verv   Sir, the reason I added image of code is, I also think that I am not choosing the right element as Choose File should have input element as its attribute.  Hence, it would be easy for anyone to guide using this image....i think :D

Comment: Your real file browser button is hidden that's why you are unable to select the element.

Comment: @Jeet Can you suggest any way to do it ?

Comment: @BryanOakley  can you please help, as I am not able to handle this problem..  :/

Answer (score 0):

Choose File should work. Problem will be in the way you're locating the element. Try using element ID instead:

```
Choose File    id=uploadChooseFile__lbo28ugd3040    C:\\Users\\Downloads\\File Name.xls
```